# What is the difference between food-grade caulk and caulk labeled for kitchen use?

Tags: kitchen-sink, caulk, silicone

I want to caulk the edges of my kitchen sink. Since I use the sink regularly to
wash food and do dishes, I want to make sure there won't be contamination.

I am considering 2 types of caulk. [This](https://www.dap.com/products-projects/product-categories/caulks-sealants/silicone/commercial-silicone/) food-grade caulk and a [general use](https://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-Advanced-Silicone-2-10-1-oz-Clear-Kitchen-and-Bath-Silicone-Sealant-Caulk-GE5040-12C/100663319) caulk
labeled for kitchen and other plumbing uses.

1. What is the difference between food-grade caulk and caulk labeled for kitchen use?
2. Is the general use caulk also safe around food and eating utensils?

Comment: I know on the food processing equipment we had to use food grade. After reading the label it appeared to be 100% silicone once cured. I really did not see anything special it may have to be mixed and loaded into the tubes in sanitary conditions but not sure.

Comment: Various toxic anti-mildew additives might be acceptable on kitchen sink caulking, but not where it comes in direct contact with food.

Comment: "Is it safe?" I would look at how long "food safe caulk" has been available and compare that to the amount of people injured by "non-food safe caulk" in the many, many years caulk has been used on kitchen sinks and faucets prior to the availability of "food safe caulk". Don't use uncured silicone or acrylic caulk as a dip on your veggie tray, and you'll probably be just fine.